# Change a variable without showing it in ISML

Tags: template, demandware

Is it possible to change a variable in ISML without showing it?

Here is what I tried:

```
<isset name="sessionVar" value="${1}" scope = "session"/>
${session.custom.sessionVar} <br/>
${session.custom.sessionVar += 1} <br/>
${session.custom.sessionVar} <br/>
```

And here is the output:

```
1.0 
2.0 
2.0
```

As we can see the variable did actually change, but it was shown twice, while I would like it to be shown once.

Here is the solution which gives me a desired output:

```
<isset name="sessionVar" value="${1}" scope = "session"/>
${session.custom.sessionVar} <br/>
<isset name="sessionVar" value="${session.custom.sessionVar += 1}" scope = "session"/>
<iscomment> ${session.custom.sessionVar += 1} <br/> </iscomment> 
${session.custom.sessionVar} <br/>
```

And here is the output for the solution:

```
1.0 
2.0
```

As we can see the solution works, but it is a crutch. That is because the semantic of the `isset` is broken, because the `isset` is designed to declare a variable, but not to modify one.

So, is there at least a solution to my problem, which is not a crutch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's discouraged to do business logic within templates. But yes, you can do scripting without output. To do so, just wrap your code with `<isscript></isscript>` eg:

```
<isscript>
  var foo = 0;
  foo++;
</isscript>
${foo}
```

outputs:

```
1
```